# How to group some records by name and pivot some values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am working on a SQL Query to group the results of a View by Id to have only one Row per Id
with a maximum of three pivoted results and keeping some columns static : TestCaseId, TestName, Test Case Num, Owner

Actually this is the Query i Created to get the Desired output but is now working as expected because the MAX is always retriving the max value so  i am getting only one row but the pivoted values are repeated to the right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  TBL1.[TestName], TBL1.[Test Case Num], TBL1.[Owner], MAX(TBL1.[Browser]) as 'Column1', MAX(TBL1.[Run Date]) as 'Column2', MAX(TBL1.[Status]) as 'Column3', MAX(TBL1.[Duration]) as 'Column4', MAX(TBL1.[ErrorMsg]) as 'Column5', MAX(TBL2.[Browser]) as 'Column6', MAX(TBL2.[Run Date]) as 'Column7', MAX(TBL2.[Status]) as 'Column8', MAX(TBL2.[Duration]) as 'Column9', MAX(TBL2.[ErrorMsg]) as 'Column10', MAX(TBL3.[Browser]) as 'Column11' , MAX(TBL3.[Run Date]) as 'Column12', MAX(TBL3.[Status]) as 'Column13', MAX(TBL3.[Duration]) as 'Column14', MAX(TBL3.[ErrorMsg]) as 'Column15' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT T1.[TestCaseId], T1.[TestName], T1.[Test Case Num], T1.[Owner], T1.[Browser], T1.[Run Date], T1.[Status], T1.[Duration], T1.[ErrorMsg]
FROM [TestRunner].[dbo].RunsRawResults T1) TBL1
cross apply (SELECT DISTINCT T2.[TestCaseId], T2.[Browser], T2.[Run Date], T2.[Status], T2.[Duration], T2.[ErrorMsg]
            FROM [TestRunner].[dbo].RunsRawResults T2
            WHERE T2.[TestCaseId] = TBL1.[TestCaseId] AND T2.[Run Date]  TBL1.[Run Date]) TBL2
cross apply (SELECT DISTINCT T3.[TestCaseId], T3.[Browser], T3.[Run Date], T3.[Status], T3.[Duration], T3.[ErrorMsg]
            FROM [TestRunner].[dbo].RunsRawResults T3
            WHERE T3.[TestCaseId] = TBL2.[TestCaseId] AND T3.[Run Date]  TBL2.[Run Date] AND  T3.[Run Date]  TBL1.[Run Date]) TBL3
            GROUP BY TBL1.[TestCaseId], TBL1.[TestName], TBL1.[Test Case Num], TBL1.[Owner]
```

Input - 
Raw Data (Comes from the RunRawResults View)
[image]
Desired and Pivoted Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) we can simplify the identification and order of multiple run dates. This also lets us skip using `distinct` and `group by`.

Switching to [**`outer apply`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) lets us include results where there are less than 3 runs per `TestCaseId`.

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by TestCaseId
        order by [Run Date]
        )
  from TestRunner.dbo.RunsRawResults
)
select 
    tbl1.TestName
  , tbl1.[Test Case Num]
  , tbl1.Owner
  , tbl1.Browser
  , [Run Date]_tbl1 = tbl1.[Run Date]
  , Status_tbl1     = tbl1.Status
  , Duration_tbl1   = tbl1.Duration
  , ErrorMsg_tbl1   = tbl1.ErrorMsg
  , Browser_tbl2    = tbl2.Browser
  , [Run Date]_tbl2 = tbl2.[Run Date]
  , Status_tbl2     = tbl2.Status
  , Duration_tbl2   = tbl2.Duration
  , ErrorMsg_tbl2   = tbl2.ErrorMsg
  , Browser_tbl3    = tbl3.Browser
  , [Run Date]_tbl3 = tbl3.[Run Date]
  , Status_tbl3     = tbl3.Status
  , Duration_tbl3   = tbl3.Duration
  , ErrorMsg_tbl3   = tbl3.ErrorMsg
from cte as tbl1
  outer apply (
    select 
        i.[Run Date]
      , i.Status
      , i.Duration
      , i.ErrorMsg
    from cte as i
    where i.TestCaseId = tbl1.TestCaseId 
      and i.rn = 2
   ) as tbl2
  outer apply (
    select 
        i.[Run Date]
      , i.Status
      , i.Duration
      , i.ErrorMsg
    from cte as i
    where i.TestCaseId = tbl1.TestCaseId 
      and i.rn = 3
   ) as tbl3
where tbl1.rn = 1
```

Comment: @Santamma Can you provide example input instead of a picture?